# Existence of cycle between any two vertices of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph

A problem to find Number of paths between two particular vertices of a directed graph and if there exists a cycle in between them then the number of paths are infinite, so I know the algorithm to find cycle in the whole graph but not any two particular vertices, so it will be helpful for me if anyone explain it.

Answer (score 1):

So, we can divide this problem into two sub parts.
If there is a cycle between **U** (source) and **V** (destination) then the answer will be infinite. So in one DFS we will start from **U** until we get **V**. Similarly starting from V until we get U. If we get reach both from both the ways then the desired answer is infinite.

Now the main part. Run a normal DFS from source U and start visiting every node as true, if you encounter the destination node that is V don't mark it as true and then simply continue from there. (Cycles in between this process can easily be detected).

Comment: n is a number of vertices and k is a number of edges  n=5 k=5  
{1 2,  
4 2,  
2 3,  
3 4,  
4 5}     and U=1 and V=5    there is no path from 5 to 1 then also it form cycle in between 1 and 5